# CSS problem: username/score appearing under icon rather than next to it

Tags: bug, design

Recently, [the site stylesheet](http://cdn.sstatic.net/mathematica/all.css?v=389f21b5fe2a) seems to have been modified to include:

```
.user-info .user-details{float:left;width:100%}
```

The `width:100%` causes the user's name and score to appear under their icon, rather than next to it:

[image: name and score under the icon]

With `width:100%` disabled, the panel is the same as it always used to be (and, I assume, as it is supposed to be):

[image: name and score next to icon]

Can anything be done about it aside from patching the CSS?

N.B.: I am using Opera 12.17, which is unfortunately unsupported by its own publisher and is now about 3 years without any major updates. This is the same as IE 10, however, and in my opinion sites should not break previously working functionality for browsers of this age.

Answer (score 7):

> I am using Opera 12.17, which is unfortunately unsupported by its own publisher and is now about 3 years without any major updates. This is the same as IE 10, however, and in my opinion sites should not break previously working functionality for browsers of this age.

I disagree with this. When most of their target audience is using browsers that are about a week to a month old, it is unreasonable to ask the developers to support a browser that is 3 years old. SE explicitly supports only the [latest two versions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161) of major browsers. The matrix of `browsers x supported versions x operating systems x window sizes` (on which all design changes need to be tested) quickly becomes too large for the developers/designers to handle, so dropping support for very old versions is understandable, as is their decision to lower the priority of bugs on fringe browsers.

Web technologies and trends change much more rapidly than traditional desktop software and security vulnerabilities often need to be patched ASAP. I highly recommend that you not use a browser that is 3 years old.

(Note that I am not in a position to comment on whether the bug should be fixed or not. It certainly is a valid report and for all we know, might be affecting modern browsers as well. My comments are independent of this and an SE developer/staff will eventually triage this.)

Comment: Well, it is a valid point of view. I would also rather not be using this old browser if a more recent alternative was available, but unfortunately that is not (yet) the case. However, the reality of it today is that most sites these days basically care about Webkit support and to hell with anything else, and I can't find myself agreeing with that.

Comment: @Oleksandr Out of curiosity why do you find other browsers undesirable?  Limited resources?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Opera is highly customizable so that one can adjust it to suit one's own workflow, and also other browsers lack many of the features I rely on, which makes the experience very uncomfortable. The "new" Opera is just a Chrome knock-off, and doesn't even provide bookmarks (!). Although, yes, you are right that memory consumption comes into it. Chrome requires as much memory to have 2 tabs open as (old) Opera does to have 20. It's not infrequent for me to open numbers of pages in the hundreds to look over at leisure.

Comment: @Oleksandr From one browser Luddite to another I appreciate your position.  I used Netscape Navigator well past the end of its support.  Then I stuck with Firefox 3.6 for a long time.  For some reason I never got into Opera, but I used and use Netscape/Mozilla products for the customizability over the market leaders then and now (MSIE/Chrome).  For security and compatibility I finally gave up older browsers but I use a somewhat lighter build of Firefox called Pale Moon.